# PrimeVue ConfirmDialog not showing

Tags: vue.js, primevue

I am using PrimeVue ConfirmDialog component as follows:

```
<template>
        <div class="py-2">
           <ConfirmDialog>HR</ConfirmDialog>
           <Button icon="pi pi-check" @click="delete ()" label="Confirm"></Button>
        </div>
</template>
    <script>
    import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue';
    import { ref, onMounted, defineComponent } from "vue";
    import { useConfirm } from "primevue/useconfirm";
    import ConfirmDialog from 'primevue/confirmdialog';
    import Button from 'primevue/button';
    
    export default {
        components: {           
            PrimaryButton,
            ConfirmDialog,
            Button
        },
        methods: {
            delete() {
                this.$confirm.require({
                    message: 'Are you sure you want to proceed?',
                    header: 'Confirmation',
                    icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
                    accept: () => {
                        //callback to execute when user confirms the action
                    },
                    reject: () => {
                        //callback to execute when user rejects the action
                    },
                    onShow: () => {
                        //callback to execute when dialog is shown
                    },
                    onHide: () => {
                        //callback to execute when dialog is hidden
                    }
                });
            },
        }
    }
    
    </script>
```

Now, I am getting an error :

```
[plugin:vite:vue] Error parsing JavaScript expression: Unexpected token (1:9)
```

which is `delete()` in the click function. I am not sure what is wrong here. If I remove the `()`, then the error disappears, but it will not trigger the function and it is not displaying the confirmation dialogue.

Comment: Where is `<div class="py-2">` located? Is there `<template>`? In case there is, please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes it is inside <template>. Updated the question

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. It's specific to your case, the code doesn't contain anything that could cause it. The error may refer to a different section, probably the file was compiled incorrectly. There's no way how `@click` could become line 1 character 9.